# minikube showing ROLES <none> on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have installed minikube first time  on my ubuntu VM 20.04 with docker driver, it started all fine until I see this and trying to understand, why it doesn't have any role assigned to it. I believe, in minikube, master and workers both sites within the same node. and I was expecting the ROLE should be `control-plane, master` but it is showing `<none>`. Any advise will be really appreciated.

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME       STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
minikube   Ready    <none>   9d    v1.22.2
```

Here is the describe node output

```
$ kubectl describe node minikube 
Name:               minikube
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=minikube
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
Annotations:        node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Wed, 10 Aug 2022 01:43:44 +0000
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  minikube
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Fri, 19 Aug 2022 11:11:38 +0000
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  MemoryPressure   False   Fri, 19 Aug 2022 11:10:31 +0000   Wed, 10 Aug 2022 01:43:44 +0000   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Fri, 19 Aug 2022 11:10:31 +0000   Wed, 10 Aug 2022 01:43:44 +0000   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Fri, 19 Aug 2022 11:10:31 +0000   Wed, 10 Aug 2022 01:43:44 +0000   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            True    Fri, 19 Aug 2022 11:10:31 +0000   Wed, 10 Aug 2022 01:43:55 +0000   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  192.168.49.2
  Hostname:    minikube
Capacity:
  cpu:                2
  ephemeral-storage:  50307616Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             3997216Ki
  pods:               110
Allocatable:
  cpu:                2
  ephemeral-storage:  50307616Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             3997216Ki
  pods:               110
System Info:
  Machine ID:                 8c119696cf5e4d94b6402a4e8e5af6fa
  System UUID:                e2800cb7-ad91-467c-89c1-9c74d75bfe1c
  Boot ID:                    4d7248d2-1670-4b3d-8823-5744a798c49b
  Kernel Version:             5.4.0-96-generic
  OS Image:                   Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               amd64
  Container Runtime Version:  docker://20.10.8
  Kubelet Version:            v1.22.2
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.22.2
PodCIDR:                      10.244.0.0/24
PodCIDRs:                     10.244.0.0/24
Non-terminated Pods:          (9 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                          CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                                          ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  kube-system                 coredns-78fcd69978-ph4w7                      100m (5%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (1%)        170Mi (4%)     9d
  kube-system                 etcd-minikube                                 100m (5%)     0 (0%)      100Mi (2%)       0 (0%)         9d
  kube-system                 kube-apiserver-minikube                       250m (12%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         9d
  kube-system                 kube-controller-manager-minikube              200m (10%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         9d
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-qg8rt                              0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         9d
  kube-system                 kube-scheduler-minikube                       100m (5%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         9d
  kube-system                 storage-provisioner                           0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         9d
  kubernetes-dashboard        dashboard-metrics-scraper-5594458c94-zktd7    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         9d
  kubernetes-dashboard        kubernetes-dashboard-654cf69797-88hv8         0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         9d
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests    Limits
  --------           --------    ------
  cpu                750m (37%)  0 (0%)
  memory             170Mi (4%)  170Mi (4%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
Events:              <none>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Does it work?  Can you, say, `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml` to it and see pods starting up?

Comment: No, I havent tried that, neither created any deployment yet, before that I am trying to see why it is not showing the roles.

Comment: If your minikube installation fundamentally works, does it matter what the `kubectl get nodes` diagnostic output says?  Why is this particular check important?

Comment: first time working with minikube or infact with k8s, so dont know if this may be an issue but let me know try deploy a service or something and see if this works.